# Rotation over time in 3D

Tags: c#, xna, rotation

Im working with Xna 4, doing a game where i have a game object (spaceship) that moves in a 3D world on the Y axis = 0 plane.. Aka 2.5D..

Until now i used a very complex angle calculation to create a rotation between 2 vectors, yet that algorithm lacks the ability to take into account that the object already is rotated. so the results get funkey.. 
Therefore i was hoping that someone, could show me a smart and easily implementable way to use Matrices and vector math, to do such a rotation over time thingy.

What i noticed in previous searches, is that people have the following variables in their object classes:
- Position vector3
- right vector3
- up vector3
- Rotation matrix
- transformMatrix matrix
- velocity vector3
- etc..

often i ask myself why its needed to have that many variables for a simple current position.. or maybe im not understanding.. anyways..

I have the position, rotation and transformsMatrix currently, and would like to know what else i need and HOW to calculate it, and then how you would implement JUST the rotation over time.

The method that is called by my right-click movement command trig sends a vector3 position on the Y = 0 plane of where the click happened.

```
public void MoveCommand(Vector3 pos){ }
```

ive tested this, and the "pos" given is accurate. Any help will be apreciated ..

Comment: I'd suggest asking this over at [gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com), I've got a feeling people over there are more familiar with this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Stig-Rune Skansgård's reply (if your danish *hi5*), i fixed my old Angle calculation and got it to work in every case.. So i thought i would answer my own question with the solution that works for me, so that future visitors can benefit of it.. This is a snippet of a very large Ship class + a helper method to calculate the angle:

```
public static float CalculateAngleFromVectors(Vector3 v1, Vector3 v2) {
        float x = 0;
        float X = v2.X - v1.X,
              Z = v2.Z - v1.Z;
        if (Z == 0) {
            x = (X < 0 ? 90 : 270);
        } else if (X == 0) {
            x = (Z < 0 ? 180 : -180);
        } else {
            float temp = MathHelper.ToDegrees((float)Math.Atan(X / Z));
            if (X < 0) {
                x = (Z < 0 ? Math.Abs(temp) : 180 - Math.Abs(temp));
            } else {
                x = (Z < 0 ? 360 - Math.Abs(temp) : Math.Abs(temp) + 180);
            }
        }
        return x;
    }
```

this method gets you the float angle (in degrees) to rotate your ship (from the standard 0 degrees starting point)..

to use it, simply make some update / animation method in your class that does something like this:

```
float desiredRotation = 0, currentRotation = 0, totalElapsed = 0, timePerFrame = 0.05f;
        if (desiredRotation != 0) {
            totalElapsed += elapsed;
            if (totalElapsed > timePerFrame) {
                if (isRotationComplete()) {
                    rotX += MathHelper.ToRadians(desiredRotation);
                    currentRotation = desiredRotation = 0;
                } else if (desiredRotation > currentRotation) {
                    currentRotation += shipTurnSpeed;
                } else if (desiredRotation < currentRotation) {
                    currentRotation -= shipTurnSpeed;
                }
                totalElapsed -= timePerFrame;
            }
        }
```

EDIT: and the completion check:

```
private bool isRotationComplete() {
        bool b = false;
        if (desiredRotation > currentRotation && currentRotation + shipTurnSpeed > desiredRotation) {
            b = true;
        } else if (desiredRotation < currentRotation && currentRotation - shipTurnSpeed < desiredRotation) {
            b = true;
        }
        return b;
    }
```

essentially what this does is to always check wether or not DesiredRotation is bigger than 0.. if it is, then that means the player has given the command to rotate (or the AI).. CurrentRotation in my example is ofc how much has been rotated since a rotation command was last given, and is set to 0 once the rotation is complete.. You should have a Rotations matrix that uses a different variable to display the rotation with.. mine is this:

```
public float rotX { get; set; }
    public float rotY { get; set; }
    public Vector3 position { get; set; }
    public Matrix Transform {
        get {
            return (Matrix.Identity *
                    Matrix.CreateScale(scale) *
                    Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.Pi) *
                    Rotation *
                    Matrix.CreateTranslation(position));
        }
    }
    public float ShipCurRotation { get { return (rotX + MathHelper.ToRadians(currentRotation)); } }
    public Matrix Rotation { get { return (Matrix.CreateRotationY(ShipCurRotation) * Matrix.CreateRotationX(rotY)); } }
```

The rotX variable is set in my animation when the rotation is complete, and also at Init.. And here is how i use the rotation angle that my first code snippet generates for me:

```
public void MoveToPosition(Vector3 pos) {
        desiredRotation = (CalculateAngleFromVectors(position, pos) - MathHelper.ToDegrees(rotX));
        isMoving = true;
    }
```

.. this makes a smooth customizable rotation, transforms and movement setup.. In a XZ plane ofc.. the Y axis is UP and always 0..

Feel free to comment on this, if you have suggestions or changes or ideas to make things even better.. Im always open for improvements.. Thanks for the replies, and hope this helps alot of new developers, took me forever to gather this stuff from the web..

PS. the rotation can be applied directly to rotX for an instant rotation, bypassing the animation and turnspeed..

WithRegards
MatriXz

Answer (score 0):

You should check the Matrix.CreateRotationX Y or Z acording to the rotation that you want.
X,Y or Z is the axis of the rotation, 
If you choose Y you will see a "2D" rotation (yaw) because that is the axis that you are using as depth.
If you choose X or Z axis you will see "3D" rotations (pitch and roll)

The code should look like this:

```
WorldMatrix = Rotations * Translation
```

where 
    Rotations = Matrix.CreateRotationX(angleRadians)
 and 
    Translation = Matrix.CreateTranslation(Position);

The world matrix is the matrix that is affecting your model, the view and projection depends on the camera

Now if you want to know the angle between vectors you should check the dot product or the atan2 function because you are in 2D

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector3 Position;
float Rotation;

Matrix World
{
    get
    {
        return Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Rotation) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(Position);
    }
}

public void RotateInstantly(Vector3 position)
{
    Rotation = Math.Atan2(Position.Y - position.Y, Position.x - position.x);
}

public void RotateIncremently(Vector3 position, float maxStep)
{
    float targetRotation = Math.Atan2(Position.Y - position.Y, Position.x - position.x);
    float diff = targetRotation - Rotation;

    if (Math.Abs(diff) > maxStep)
    {
        if (targetRotation > Rotation)
            Rotation += maxStep;
        else
            Rotation -= maxStep;
    }
    else
        Rotation = targetRotation;
}
```

You can use the RotateIncremently like this:*
float dt = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

float maxRotationVelocity = Math.TwoPi; //2* Pi is one revolution.

RotateIncremently(target.Position, maxRotationVelocity * dt);

Comment: okay i liked this approach, tryed it out, but for some reason it gives really strange results.. How would you calculate the Rotation float in your example?

Comment: Well, it should only depend on which plane your gameplay acts on. If you are moving things about in the XY-plane, it should work, I think. BUT maybe you are affected by the fact that Atan2 returns 0 to -Pi in some cases. to fix that:

if (targetRotation < 0f)
targetRotation = MathHelper.TwoPi - targetRotation;

even then though. you might have some problems when crossing 0... hmm..